# Oil absorbed into human skin -- where does it go?

Tags: skin, lipids, membrane-transport

For example, I apply petrolatum to my dry hands twice a day as in winter I am usually in a 20-30% RH environment.  Within an hour, the petrolatum seems entirely absorbed.

According to [1], petrolatum and the other oils tested there "do not reach the viable cells of epidermis, saturating only the uppermost horny layers of the skin."

So my question is: Where does the oil go?   I do not believe I am shedding unseen skin layers fast enough nor transferring the oil to other objects fast enough that I can repeat and apply twice a day, without the oil going deeper than "uppermost horny layers" and being excreted internally. (Via lymph? blood?)  Also, I rarely wash my hands with soap.

[1] Confocal Raman microscopy for investigating the penetration of various oils into the human skin in vivo.
Choe C, Lademann J, Darvin ME.
J Dermatol Sci. 2015 Aug.
https://atlasofscience.org/oil-penetration-into-the-human-skin/
Accessed 2/8/2019